# How to prevent shard failure in elasticsearch when dealing with reciprocal function

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have to perform an elastic search query, where I need to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by the query. I am using function_score to modify the score with the help of reciprocal function. Following is my code,

```
{
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{"match":{"course": "IT"}}]
                }
            },
            "functions": [{
                    "field_value_factor": {
                        "field": "users_score_nested.rank",
                        "modifier": "reciprocal",
                        "missing": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost_mode": "multiply",
            "score_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
```

Here I need to alter my score based on the filter on course field as well as the rank field. Rank value can have values like 0, NULL, 1, 2. A score should be high for a candidate who is having a high rank(Least rank value). But because of 0 or NULL value shard failing occurs. Is there a way to prevent the shard from failing other than changing the rank values Or Can I use any other function other than the reciprocal function?

The error I am getting is as follows,

```
{
    "root_cause": [{
        "type": "exception",
        "reason": "Result of field modification [reciprocal(0.0)] must be a number"
    }],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is remove the "users_score_nested.rank" from the data so that "missing" parameter of the function_score query kicks in and the reciprocal is 1.

I am afraid that there is no way to bypass the exception. Alternatively you can use script_score parameter of function_score query

```
"script_score" : {
            "script" : {
                "source": "Math.pow(doc['users_score_nested']['rank']+1,-1)"
            }
        }
```

NOTE: Ensure that the `"type"` of the `"rank"` field is `"integer"` and it is included in the parent as part of the mappings.

Comment: Math.pow function will increase the score when rank value increase, but in my case it should decrease. Say Rank 1 should come on top where as rank 10 should come less.

Comment: I guess Math.pow(<any-number>, -1) is same as reciprocal. You may check the same by firing the above query on a smaller dataset and verifying the corresponding scores.

Comment: I tried this method, but fails when the value is either 0 or NULL

Comment: I assume that rank is a non-negative integer. This would fail if rank is -1 anywhere in the data.

Comment: In my case rank values can include 0 and NULL

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to prevent the shard failure. I have done as follows which helped me from failing of shards.

```
{
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{"match":{"course": "IT"}},
                         {"terms":{"users_score_nested.rank": [1, 2]}}]
            }
        },
        "functions": [{
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "users_score_nested.rank",
                    "modifier": "reciprocal",
                    "missing": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "boost_mode": "multiply",
        "score_mode": "sum"
    }
}
```

Here, **first it will filter the data based on the bool query, then on the filtered data only ES will perform the score calcuation**. So the rank values which cause shard failure, i.e 0 and NULL will be filtered out.